# How to make dropdowns etc remember their last selected values in subsequent page loads in MVC4

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

We have a multi-step survey form in a dashboard. Sometimes users start filling the form, get distracted and then click some button in the dashboard which takes them elsewhere in the site. Then when they click the back button, what they already filled in the form is gone.

Is there some way to ensure that the form stays filled when they come back? In ASP.NET webforms, I'd put the values in the Session object and populate survey form on page load. How should I solve this problem with MVC4?

Comment: You could save the values to a cookie or run some ajax when the select onChange() event is fired.

Comment: Thanks @KevDevMan. Guess firing an ajax to save the suvery answers as user progresses works. Is the ajax supposed to go to a controller or web api (or WCF or some other variant)? I understand the mechanics of all of the above but unsure of what the best practice for handling this type of scenario would be in the MVC world? Are all these approaches equivalent in terms of best design practices?

Comment: Where you send the ajax depends on your set up. You can send it to any layer. If you are using API/knockout or equivalent then you send to API, other wise you can send it to the MVC controller. In design terms you really don't want to be saving off every single input onChange. I would suggest you save for each step of the multi-step survey when the users clicks next or previous. Best practices is to make a few calls as possible to you servers.

Comment: Thanks @KevDevMan, I appreciate the advice. I ended up sending Ajax to the controller which in turn saved the survey answers in the Session object. If Session proves to be too expensive in further tests, I'll try out saving to a tempdb or cookie etc. I put the survey in a partial view so that it was able to refresh itself on form submit, thereby eliminating the need of page-onload client side code.